# Superclass Variable not Working for CFAbsoluteTime

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've had a problem with a function defined in a superclass not working. After a bit of investigation it turns out that a variable defined in the superclass is not working in the subclass despite the code hinting recognising it and the code running and I'm totally stumped after a lot of fiddling:

```
class Super {

    //records absolute time of last frame
    var timeThen: Double = 0

    func getElapsedTime () -> CGFloat {
        //records current time
        let timeNow = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        //finds duration since last update
        let duration = timeNow-timeThen
        //resets timeThen to current time for next run
        timeThen = timeNow
        //casts Double value to CGFloat and returns
        return CGFloat(duration)
    }

    init () {
        timeThen = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }

}
```

The subclass is as follows:

```
class Sub: Super {

    //gets time from function but doesn't work and seems to run incredibly slowly
    let timeElapsed = getElapsedTime()
    //run code based on interval
}
```

So I tried to do it manually:

```
class Sub: Super {

    //still doesn't work
    let timeNow = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let timeElapsed = CGFloat(timeNow-timeThen)
    timeThen = timeNow
    //run code based on interval

}
```

But if I use a variable defined in the subclass its all works perfectly:

```
class Sub: Super {

    //new variable to replace 'faulty' one 
    var timeThen2: Double = 0

    // Now it works
    let timeNow = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let timeElapsed = CGFloat(timeNow-timeThen2)
    timeThen2 = timeNow
    // run code based on interval
}
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Kw

Comment: What does *"doesn't work"* mean? – And none of your `class Sub` examples compiles, so what does *"seems to run incredibly slowly"* mean?

Comment: I found the problem. The object was being updated twice per frame making the time difference between the updates negligible. This resulted in the code, which related the time difference to sprite motion, move the sprite extremely slowly. Thanks for the help.